# Debug.setlocal() security concerns

Tags: security, debugging, lua, exploit

Is there any security concerns todo with debug.setlocal? If so can you please tell me how exactly it works.

Comment: This function must not be available in a sandboxed environment.

Answer (score 1):

Lua threads run on top of a "stack", a list of items that make up most of the memory in the language. Everything, from "global" variables to tables, sits happily on this list.

When you create a local variable and execute your code, the stack would look something like this:

```lua
local a = "the letter a"
```

```
STACK
+---+----------------+
| 1 | "the letter a" |
+---+----------------+
```

Now, let's say we are malicious code. We know that the following code is used to run our program:

```lua
local isAdministrator = false
local Code = "malicious code here!"
loadstring(Code)()
```

Well, that means the stack of the **loader** looks something like this:

```
+---+-------+
| 1 | false | isAdministrator
+---+-------+----------------+
| 2 | "malicious code here!" | Code
+---+---------------------+--+
| 3 | function loadstring |
+---+---------------------+--+
| 4 | function MaliciousCode |
+---+------------------------+
```

Now, let's say changing `isAdministrator` is of some value to us. Let's look at how we would do that.

`1` We need to get lua to modify the "stack" above our function. Imagine lua is a tree, like so:

```
otherScript
 + loader
    + maliciousCode
```

Each step in this tree has it's own stack, and each variable from the stack above it is "accessible" to the stack below it, thanks to the `debug` library.

If the "stack" we are currently on is stack #1 (which is always true)
Then the function that called the current function is on stack #2 (which is almost always true)

Now, looking at the stack of the function we want to change, `isAdministrator` is in slot `1`, the first one. So, to change this, we juuuust:

```lua
debug.setlocal(2,1,true)
```

And bam. `isAdministrator` is now `true`. We are free to ruin your computer!

Do not fret- there is a way to stop this. It is really easy to take away the debug library:

```lua
local func = loadstring("malicious code!")
setfenv(func, {
    --  Here we insert what functions our baby function can use. Let's give it the string, table, and math libraries- which are pretty safe
    math = math, table = table, string = string,
    --  Oh, and let's give it the `os.time` function as well.
    os = { time = os.time }
})
func()
```

Now, func *cannot* access the debug library, and you are free to use your silly `isAdministrator` locals in peace.